# What to do when laravel routing is duplicated in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have added two routes, as described below.

I want the following behavior.
/api/user/1 or /api/user/2 or . . . → **UserController@show** is excute

/api/user/auth → **UserController@showAuthUser** is excute

However, when call /api/user/auth, **UserController@show** is excuted.

How do I get what I want?

```
Route::get('user/{user_id}', 'Api\UserController@show');

Route::get('user/auth', 'Api\UserController@showAuthUser');
```

Comment: What error are you facing ?

Comment: When calling /api/user/auth, the problem is that UserController@show is executed.

What I want executed is UserController@showAuthUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your routes with fixed "parameters" first :

```
Route::get('user/auth', 'Api\UserController@showAuthUser');
Route::get('user/{user_id}', 'Api\UserController@show');
```

If you put {user_id} first, Laravel will put "auth" in your "user_id" variable

Comment: Thank you! It went well in the way you taught!

Answer (score 1):

Switch the order of your routes

```
Route::get('user/auth', 'Api\UserController@showAuthUser');
Route::get('user/{user_id}', 'Api\UserController@show');
```

Otherwise it expects 'auth' to be a 'user_id'

Comment: I didn't know that the one described earlier had priority. Thank you for teaching me!